# Refactoring battleship game

Tags: ruby

I'm creating a battleship game in Ruby.
Let me explain how it works:

- The game is played on 5x5 grids (one per player).
- Players have 2 ships each to place on their grid. A small ship (3x1 side) and a large one (4x1 size).
- Players are asked in turn to place their ships on their board. A ship can't be placed out of bounds nor on the same space as another ship.
- Players take turns to shoot at the opponent grid one after the other by selecting coordinates.
- The first player to reach 7 points (all boats sinked) wins the game.

As you can see, some parts of my code are very repetitive:

- I ask to each player to place its 2 ships so I have the "same" code 4 times (`--- PLACEMENT OF THE SIZE 3 SHIP OF #{name_p1.upcase} ---`).
- I ask players to take turns to shoot at the opponent grid one after the other (this is done twice).
- Same problem when I print the result of a shot.

I'm very struggling to refactor my code to make it simpler and shorter.
How can it be simplified?

```
# Board for player 1
board1 = []
for i in 0..4
  board1[i] = []
  (0..4).each do
    board1[i].append('O')
  end
end

# Board for player 2
board2 = []
for i in 0..4
  board2[i] = []
  (0..4).each do
    board2[i].append('O')
  end
end

# Display the boards
def display_board(board)
  for row in board
    puts row.map { |k| "#{k}" }.join('  ')
  end
end

def check_obstacle(ship_size, player_array, posX, posY, direction)
  check = 0
  @ship_present = 0
  @space_available = 0

  @ship_present += 1 if player_array[posX][posY] == 1
  @space_available += 1 if player_array[posX][posY] == 0
  while check < ship_size && @space_available < ship_size
    case direction
    when 'north' then posX -= 1
    when 'east' then posY += 1
    when 'south' then posX += 1
    when 'west' then posY -= 1
    end
    
    @space_available += 1 if posX.between?(0, 4) && posY.between?(0, 4)
    @ship_present += 1 if posX.between?(0, 4) && posY.between?(0, 4) && player_array[posX][posY] == 1
    check += 1
  end
  @space_available == ship_size && @ship_present == 0
end

def ship_placement(ship_size, player_array, posX, posY, direction)
  steps = 0

  while steps < ship_size && @ship_present == 0 && @space_available == ship_size
    player_array[posX][posY] = 1
    case direction
    when 'north' then posX -= 1
    when 'east' then posY += 1
    when 'south' then posX += 1
    when 'west' then posY -= 1
    end
    steps += 1
  end
  puts "The ship of size #{ship_size} is placed."
end

# Generation of the player boards
array1 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
array2 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

# A player wins when he/she reaches 7 points (2 ships each to place on their grid : a small ship (3x1 side) and a large one (4x1 size))
solution = 7

# We set the number of points at 0 at the start of the game
points_p1 = 0
points_p2 = 0

#Starting of the game and printing the board 
while true do
  puts 'Welcome soldiers!'
  puts 'To start the game, enter "start". To quit, enter "stop":'
  starting = gets.chomp
  puts "\n"

  case starting.downcase
  when 'start'
    puts 'Enter the first name of the first player:'
    name_p1 = gets.chomp.to_s
    puts "\n"
    puts 'Enter the first name of the second player:'
    name_p2 = gets.chomp.to_s
    puts "\n"

    puts "--- PLACEMENT OF THE SIZE 3 SHIP OF #{name_p1.upcase} ---"
    while true
      while true
        puts 'Enter LINE number (between 1 and 5):'
        placement_row = gets.chomp.to_i-1
        break if placement_row.between?(0, 4)
      end

      while true
        puts 'Enter COLUMN number (between 1 and 5):'
        placement_column = gets.chomp.to_i-1
        break if placement_column.between?(0, 4)
      end

      while true
        puts "Enter ship direction (north, east, south ou west)"
        orientation = gets.chomp.downcase
        break if %w(north east south west).include? orientation
      end

      if check_obstacle(3, array1, placement_row, placement_column, orientation)
        ship_placement(3, array1, placement_row, placement_column, orientation)
        break
      else
        puts "Unable to place. Please try again."
      end
    end

    puts "--- PLACEMENT OF THE SIZE 4 SHIP OF #{name_p1.upcase} ---"
    while true
      while true
        puts 'Enter LINE number (between 1 and 5):'
        placement_row = gets.chomp.to_i-1
        break if placement_row.between?(0, 4)
      end

      while true
        puts 'Enter COLUMN number (between 1 and 5):'
        placement_column = gets.chomp.to_i-1
        break if placement_column.between?(0, 4)
      end

      while true
        puts "Enter ship direction (north, east, south ou west)"
        orientation = gets.chomp.downcase
        break if %w(north east south west).include? orientation
      end

      if check_obstacle(4, array1, placement_row, placement_column, orientation)
        ship_placement(4, array1, placement_row, placement_column, orientation)
        break
      else
        puts "Unable to place. Please try again."
      end
    end
###############################################################
    puts "--- PLACEMENT OF THE SIZE 3 SHIP OF #{name_p2.upcase} ---"
    while true
      while true
        puts 'Enter LINE number (between 1 and 5):'
        placement_row = gets.chomp.to_i-1
        break if placement_row.between?(0, 4)
      end

      while true
        puts 'Enter COLUMN number (between 1 and 5):'
        placement_column = gets.chomp.to_i-1
        break if placement_column.between?(0, 4)
      end

      while true
        puts "Enter ship direction (north, east, south ou west)"
        orientation = gets.chomp.downcase
        break if %w(north east south west).include? orientation
      end

      if check_obstacle(3, array2, placement_row, placement_column, orientation)
        ship_placement(3, array2, placement_row, placement_column, orientation)
        break
      else
        puts "Unable to place. Please try again."
      end
    end

    puts "--- PLACEMENT OF THE SIZE 4 SHIP OF #{name_p2.upcase} ---"
    while true
      while true
        puts 'Enter LINE number (between 1 and 5):'
        placement_row = gets.chomp.to_i-1
        break if placement_row.between?(0, 4)
      end

      while true
        puts 'Enter COLUMN number (between 1 and 5):'
        placement_column = gets.chomp.to_i-1
        break if placement_column.between?(0, 4)
      end

      while true
        puts "Enter ship direction (north, east, south ou west)"
        orientation = gets.chomp.downcase
        break if %w(north east south west).include? orientation
      end

      if check_obstacle(4, array2, placement_row, placement_column, orientation)
        ship_placement(4, array2, placement_row, placement_column, orientation)
        break
      else
        puts "Unable to place. Please try again."
      end
    end

    while points_p1 < solution || points_p2 < solution
      puts "--- #{name_p1.upcase}'S TURN ---"
      while true
        puts 'Enter LINE number (between 1 and 5):'
        row_p1 = gets.chomp.to_i-1
        break if row_p1.between?(0, 4)
      end
      while true
        puts 'Enter COLUMN number (between 1 and 5):'
        column_p1 = gets.chomp.to_i-1
        break if column_p1.between?(0, 4)
      end
      
      # Shot fired!
      case array1[row_p1][column_p1]
      when 1
        board1[row_p1][column_p1] = 'X'
        array1[row_p1][column_p1] = 'X'
        points_p1 += 1
      when 0
        board1[row_p1][column_p1] = '-'
        array1[row_p1][column_p1] = '-'
      when 'X', '-'
        puts 'Square already played.'
        next
      end

      puts "\n"
      puts '--------------'
      display_board(board1)
      puts '--------------'
      puts '----------------------'
      puts "#{name_p1} has #{points_p1} point#{"s" if points_p1 > 1}."
      puts '----------------------'
      puts "\n"

    break if points_p1 == solution

      puts "--- #{name_p2.upcase}'S TURN ---"
      while true
        puts 'Enter LINE number (between 1 and 5):'
        row_p2 = gets.chomp.to_i-1
        break if row_p2.between?(0, 4)
      end
      while true
        puts 'Enter COLUMN number (between 1 and 5):'
        column_p2 = gets.chomp.to_i-1
        break if column_p2.between?(0, 4)
      end

      # Shot fired!
      case array2[row_p2][column_p2]
      when 1
        board2[row_p2][column_p2] = 'X'
        array2[row_p1][column_p1] = 'X'
        points_p2 += 1
      when 0
        board2[row_p2][column_p2] = '-'
      when 'X', '-'
        next
      end

      puts "\n"
      puts '--------------'
      display_board(board2)
      puts '--------------'
      puts '----------------------'
      puts "#{name_p2} has #{points_p2} point#{"s" if points_p2 > 1}."
      puts '----------------------'
      puts "\n"
      break if points_p2 == solution
    end

    puts "Congratulations #{name_p1}, you have destroyed all the enemy ships!" if points_p1 == solution
    puts "Congratulations #{name_p2}, you have destroyed all the enemy ships!" if points_p2 == solution
    puts "\n"
    break

  when 'stop'
    puts 'See you soon!'
    break
  else
    puts 'Please make a choice between "start". To exit, enter "stop".'
    puts "\n"
  end
end
```

Comment: You might try this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead of here, but having said that, I'd be looking for a more object oriented approach, with a Ship class, Board class, and an interface like `Board1.add(Ship.new(size: 3), start_coords: [0,2], orientation: :up_down)` and `result = Board1.shoot_at(row: 2, col: 3)`. Ruby is object oriented, and really ought to be written that way.

Answer (score 0):

As David mentions in his comment, you really want to make use of Ruby's object oriented features.

Here are some components I put together and some example usage. (Seemed like a fun exercise ... I guess I got carried away.)

```
class ShipPoint
    attr_reader :row, :column, :owner
    attr_accessor :hit

    def initialize(row,column, owner)
        @row = row
        @column = column
        @owner = owner
        @hit = false
    end

    def to_s
        @hit ? "X" : owner.label
    end
end

class Ship
    attr_reader :points, :name
    attr_accessor :owner

    def initialize(row:, column:, size:, direction:, name: nil, owner: nil)
        @name = name 
        @owner = owner
        case direction
        when "north"
            @points = (0...size).map { ShipPoint.new(row - _1, column, self) }
        when "south"
            @points = (0...size).map { ShipPoint.new(row + _1, column, self) }
        when "east"
            @points = (0...size).map { ShipPoint.new(row, column + _1, self) }
        when "west"
            @points = (0...size).map { ShipPoint.new(row, column - _1, self) }
        end
    end

    def sunk?()
        @points.all? {_1.hit}
    end

    def column_range()
        Range.new(*@points.minmax_by {_1.column}.map {_1.column})
    end

    def row_range()
        Range.new(*@points.minmax_by {_1.row}.map {_1.row})
    end

    def point(row,column)
        @points.find {_1.row == row && _1.column == column}
    end

    def label()
        return @name[0] if @name
        owner.ships.index(self).to_s
    end
end

class Board
    attr_reader :range, :ships

    def initialize(size=5)
        @range = Range.new(0, size-1)
        @content = Array.new(size) {Array.new(size)}
        @ships = []
    end

    def add_ship(ship)
        placeable = range.cover?(ship.column_range) && range.cover?(ship.row_range) && ship.points.all? {available?(_1.row, _1.column)}
        if placeable
            ship.owner = self
            @ships << ship
            ship.points.each {|p| @content[p.row][p.column] = ship}
        else
            puts "ship is unplaceable"
        end
    end

    def to_s
        display = ""
        @content.each_index  do |row| 
            row_display = ""
            @content[row].each_index do |column|
                location = @content[row][column]
                row_display << (location ? location.point(row,column).to_s : ".")
            end
            display << "#{row_display}\n"
        end
        display
    end

    def available?(row, column)
        @content[row][column].nil? 
    end

    def target(row:,column:)
        ship = @content[row][column]
        point = ship&.point(row,column)
        point&.hit = true
        sunk = ship&.sunk?
        all_sunk = @ships.all? {_1.sunk?}
        case 
        when all_sunk then "all sunk"
        when sunk then "Sunk: #{ship.name}" 
        when point&.hit then :hit
        else :miss
        end
    end
end

b1 = Board.new
b2 = Board.new
s1 = Ship.new(row: 0, column: 1, size: 4, direction: "north")
s2 = Ship.new(row: 0, column: 1, size: 4, direction: "south", name: "Battle Ship")
s3 = Ship.new(row: 0, column: 1, size: 4, direction: "east")
s4 = Ship.new(row: 0, column: 1, size: 4, direction: "west")
s5 = Ship.new(row: 4, column: 0, size: 3, direction: "east")
b1.add_ship(s1)
b1.add_ship(s2)
b1.add_ship(s3)
b1.add_ship(s4)
b1.add_ship(s5)


puts b1
puts "result = #{b1.target(row: 0, column: 0)}"
puts "result = #{b1.target(row: 0, column: 1)}"
puts "result = #{b1.target(row: 1, column: 1)}"
puts "result = #{b1.target(row: 2, column: 1)}"
puts "result = #{b1.target(row: 3, column: 1)}"
puts "result = #{b1.target(row: 4, column: 0)}"
puts "result = #{b1.target(row: 4, column: 1)}"
puts "result = #{b1.target(row: 4, column: 2)}"

puts b1
```